# Eclipse doesn't recognize smartcardio library

Tags: java, eclipse, smartcardio

After migration from Sun's jdk (1.8) to Openjdk12 - Eclipse does not recognize the whole library of "javax.smartcardio".

**for example:**

```
import javax.smartcardio.Card;
```

will cause the errors

```
Card cannot be resolved to a type

The import javax.smartcardio cannot be resolved
```

We've tried to add the "src.zip" to the JRE coniguration in the Eclipse, but its content does not appear in "Project Explorer"...

Comment: What's your import statement look like? You can't import a package, just a type or a wildcard for all of its types.

Comment: Unfortunately Java's Smart Card library has never been included in the source or documentation. It's a separate compile, so it is not a surprise that including `src.zip` doesn't solve your issues. Your question needs more detail on your project setup, platform etc. to be able to be solved.

Comment: I works with @shlomi Levy on the same project.

The project is built by Maven *successfully*.

Answer (score 8):

Eclipse-Version (Look at the pictures.)

1. Right click on the project -> Configure Build Path... [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4dCa.jpg)
2. Module Dependencies -> **add** System Module... [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSWM5.jpg)
3. **add** java.smartcardio (**not** javax.smartcardio) [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMGjB.jpg)
4. **check** Module -> Apply and Close [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/go23o.jpg)