# javax.smartcardio* not recognized in java17 in eclipse in a non module project

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse, java-17

I am facing the problem in eclipse while migrating a project from java8 to java17 which uses javax.smartcardio. I have build error saying "CardTerminal cannot be resolved to a type" as the javax.smartcardio* are not recognized. I cannot add module-info.java as mine in a Non module project.

I have maven setup. I have checked that adding missing module "java.smartcardio" in build path->"Libraries" will resolve build errors but, this is specific to developer system and I need a sustainable solution where in any developer takes latest from git should not have to fix it each time in development box to get rid of build errors. Also, this should not affect the automated build process to generate jars / cause run time class not found issues etc

Comment: Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58917664/eclipse-doesnt-recognize-smartcardio-library

Comment: I have already tried this, but I want a fix for this so that I don’t want every developer who takes code from git will have to change the build path. I am looking for a sustainable fix which works in all dev boxes and automated build process

Comment: Automated build pipelines are not a problem if you specify the jar in the classpath correctly. This issue is mainly with the IDEs like Eclipse and Intellij both of which seem to have open issues around these libraries.